How to prefill Claude project's first user message from GET param?
I was looking for something similar to non-project Claude threads, like https://claude.ai/new?q=prefilled+question which work great and very handy for my use cases.
But for project threads it doesn't seem to make any changes:
https://claude.ai/project/xxxxxxxx-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-zzzzzzzzzzzz?q=hello+world

As a workaround, the following browser bookmark item seems to be working for now:
javascript:(function(){const q=new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('q')||'';const d=document.querySelector('div[contenteditable="true"]');if(d){const p=d.querySelector('p');if(p)p.innerHTML=q;}})();

but it may break later if HTML layout changes.
